# Having Issue on Getting Fields Name Using MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to list name of the fields in a table `charts-single-tbl` by using this code:

```
$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);
$query4 = "SELECT *  FROM `charts-single-tbl`" ;
$results = $con->query($query4);
$rows = $results->fetch_fields();
echo $rows->name; 
$con->close();
```

but I am getting this error

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`mysqli_result::fetch_fields()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php) provides a return value as an array of objects.

> mysqli_fetch_fields — Returns an array of objects representing the fields in a result set

Your variable `$rows` is therefore an array but you're trying to access it as a single object. You'll need to loop over it to get all field names in your table.

```
$fields = $results->fetch_fields();
// $fields is an array. Loop over it to get name properties
foreach ($fields as $field) {
  echo $field->name . "\n";
}
```

#### Alternatively...

If you intend to fetch the actual row values eventually anyway, you might consider just starting the fetch loop with `fetch_assoc()` and using the array keys to find the field names.

```
$results = $con->query($query4);
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
  // Fields are the keys of $row
  $fields = array_keys($row);
  // do whatever else you intend to do with $row values
}
```

#### On debugging...

When PHP complains of mismatched or misused types, such as *Trying to get property of non-object*, debugging it with a simple `var_dump($rows)` may immediately point what's gone wrong. In this case it would have revealed the array structure.